# Getting 404 Component NOT FOUND error while upadating component from 2.5 to 3.2

Tags: components, joomla2.5, upgrade, joomla3.0, issue-tracking

I created joomla custom component and installed without any errors. But when I'm trying to access the component it throws me 404 , component not found error.I created joomla custom component and installed without any errors. But when I'm trying to access the component it throws me 404 , component not found error.
Here is my XML code.

```
<name>JoomListings</name>   

<creationDate>2010-10-11</creationDate>

<author>JoomClan.com</author>

<authorEmail>joomclan@gmail.com</authorEmail>

<authorUrl>http://www.JoomClan.com</authorUrl>

<copyright>Copyright 2009-2010</copyright>


<license>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html GNU/GPL</license>

<version>3.2</version>

<description>

    Joomlistings a Classified component from Joomclan.com. Create a classifieds in minutes. 

</description>

<install>

    <sql folder="admin">

        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">install.joomlistings.sql</file>
    </sql>

</install>

<uninstall>
    <sql folder="admin">

        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">uninstall.joomlistings.sql</file>

    </sql>
</uninstall>

<files folder="site">

    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>download.php</filename>
    <filename>expressInstall.swf</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>jlcron.php</filename>
    <filename>joomlistings.php</filename>
    <filename>router.php</filename>
    <filename>short.php</filename>
    <filename>uploadify.php</filename>
    <filename>uploadify.swf</filename>
    <folder>controllers</folder>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>helpers</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
    <folder>includes</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>views</folder>

</files>

<languages folder="lang">

        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_joomlistings.ini</language>

</languages>
<!--
    <files folder="component"> <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>images/index.html</filename> </files>
-->
<administration>

    <!-- Administration Menu Section -->
    <menu>Joomlistings</menu>

    <files folder="admin">
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>admin.joomlistings.html.php</filename>
        <filename>admin.joomlistings.php</filename>
        <filename>toolbar.joomlistings.html.php</filename>
        <filename>toolbar.joomlistings.php</filename>
        <filename>install.joomlistings.sql</filename>
        <filename>uninstall.joomlistings.sql</filename>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
        <folder>images</folder>
        <folder>includes</folder>
        <folder>js</folder>
        <folder>modules</folder>
        <folder>plugins</folder>
        <folder>styles</folder>
        <folder>tables</folder>
        <folder>sql</folder>
    </files>

    <languages folder="admin/lang">

                     <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_joomlistings.ini</language>
            </languages>

</administration>
```

Comment: where are you accessing the component from?

Comment: I am accessing component from Admin side

Comment: What is the url which returns 404?

Comment: Do you have the base controller file controller.php in your component?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the extension is ccompatible with your version of joomla?

Have you tried asking the support team of that extension?

Comment: it is not compatible with 3x joomla but i made some changes in xml file only and then i installed it .it installed suceessfully but i getting 404 error in admin panel .

Comment: I dont know enough to give you an answer but i would have a look at the changes that were made for route.php between the joomla versions and how the url gets created. My guess is that you need to do more than just change the xml